# Azure Notification Hub, Preview capability

Tags: azure-notificationhub

Is there a way in Notification hub to preview the push notification on simulators/devices before they are pushed to real user's devices? if not, what approach can be utilized here?

Thanks,

Vineet

Answer (score 0):

At this time a preview feature is not available on Azure Notification hub.You can leave your feedback/ feature request on [Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs). All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can successfully send push notifications to the Android Emulator. You cannot do the same with the iOS Simulator, due to the fact the Simulator just doesn't allow for it.

You can also use a physical device and using a unique tag, or just logging out a registration or installation ID, you could send a notification directly to your own development devices before sending out to real users. This would allow you to validate behavior and appearances before sending to real users. So basically the same process you would use to validate any kind of UI changes before sending an App update out to users. Try on your own devices first.

Hope that helps! :)